# Question on the theorem of total probability

Tags: probability

**Theorem:** If the events $B_1,B_2,...,B_k$ constitue a partition of the sample $S$ such that $P(B_i) \neq 0$ for $i=1,2,...,k$, then for **any event $\boldsymbol{R}$ of $\boldsymbol{S}$**
$$P(R)=\sum_{i=1}^{k} P(B_i) P(R|B_i).$$
I found an example

[image]

but I can not understand **what is the sample space $S$** in this example and **how can $\boldsymbol{R}$ belong to $\boldsymbol{S}$?**
Can you help me to explain in more details. Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is no $R$ in your equation.

Comment: The $R$ in the linked image is the same as the $A$ in your post

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy $R$ is in the image.  If the sample space is the ways of choosing a bag and then the marble, then a subset of this is the event that the marble is red

Comment: Oh I am sorry. I have a typos mistake when typing R (instead of A). I have eddited.

Comment: It's much better to link to the [original source](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter1/1_4_2_total_probability.php) than to take a screenshot.

Comment: Since the question is "What is the probability the marble chosen is Red?"  the sample space is {R, B}, Red and Blue, the two possible colors for the chosen marble.  "R", the event that the chosen marble is red, is clearly a member of the set {R, B}.

Answer (score 1):

Make a double entry table to represent $S$, with three rows that have all the possible choices of bags ($b_1,b_2,b_3$) and two columns representing all the possible choices of marble color ($B,R$). Then write all possible pairs you get in the entries. For example the first raw will be $(b_1,B),(b_1,R)$ and so on. $S$ is simply all these pairs you get in the double entry table, and $R$ is composed by the entries on the second column.